# Create a Function that Sorts and Numbers List

Tags: python

I want to create/call a function that first sorts a list of strings, and then then displays each item on the list, one per line in sorted & numerical order.

```
# This is an incomplete function
list = ["Hello", "Friend", "Apple", "Banana"]
def sorted()
    sortedlist = sorted(list)
    for i in sortedlist:
        print (i)
```

The end result would look like this:

1. Apple
2. Banana
3. Friend
4. Hello

I suppose that once the list is sorted, then concat a 1, 2, 3 and so on for each item in the list, and then print?

Comment: That's a requirement, not a programming question. What have you done, and what problems did you run into in the process?

Comment: name `list` something else so as not to shadow the built-in `list`, then do `print(list(enumerate(my_list)))`?

Comment: Don't use the function name `sorted()` as that's actually a built-in function in Python. If you remove your definition (or rename it) and do `sorted(array)` you will notice it will actually return the sorted list.

Comment: The enumerate functions looks like the way to go once the list is sorted, thank you!  I will also avoid using the built-in function.

Comment: To more directly answer your question, you want two functions: (1) One that will actually sort and return the sorted array. (2) One that will print your array. The print portion (#2) you have it right with the `for-loop` but as @GreenClockGuy mentioned, enumerate would work best for your goal; for the sorting portion (#1) it's no bueno. If you want to create your own custom sorting function, check out this resource [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEJyjB1oGzx2h88Tj90B5_HadLq339Cso).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python have a built in function for string natural sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to do this is with `enumerate` which generates a tuple for each element in the list, the first element being the label, the second being the item itself. If you want to start at 1:

```
sortedlist = sorted(list)

for i in enumerate(sortedlist, start=1):
    print(f"{i[0]}. {i[1]}")
```